# Comparing collection contents with ScalaTest

Tags: unit-testing, scala, scalatest

I'm trying to unit-test some Scala that is very collection-heavy. These collections are returned as `Iterable[T]`, so I am interested in the *contents* of the collection, even if the underlying types differ. This is actually two related problems:

1. How do I assert that two **ordered** collections contain the same sequence of elements?
2. How do I assert that two **unordered** collections contain the same set of elements?

In summary, I'm looking the Scala-equivalent of NUnit's `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` (ordered) and `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` (unordered) in ScalaTest:

```
Set(1, 2) should equal (List(1, 2))          // ordered, pass
Iterable(2, 1) should equal (Iterable(1, 2)) // unordered, pass
```

Comment: For the unordered case, if you're not worried about a bit of extra memory usage, you could call `.toSet` on the collections you want to compare.

Comment: Calling `toSet` is exactly the behavior I want, but it behaves incorrectly if the collection contains duplicate elements.

Comment: You could possibly use the `groupBy` method, and pass in some identity function as the mapper.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could try `.toSeq` for ordered collections and `.toSet` for unordered, which captures what you want as far as I understand it.

The following passes:

```
class Temp extends FunSuite with ShouldMatchers {
  test("1")  { Array(1, 2).toSeq should equal (List(1, 2).toSeq) }
  test("2")  { Array(2, 1).toSeq should not equal (List(1, 2).toSeq) }
  test("2b") { Array(2, 1) should not equal (List(1, 2)) }  
  test("3")  { Iterable(2, 1).toSet should equal (Iterable(1, 2).toSet) }
  test("4")  { Iterable(2, 1) should not equal (Iterable(1, 2)) }
}
```

BTW a `Set` is not ordered.

**edit:** To avoid removing duplicate elements, try `toSeq.sorted`. The following pass:

```
  test("5")  { Iterable(2, 1).toSeq.sorted should equal (Iterable(1, 2).toSeq.sorted) }
  test("6")  { Iterable(2, 1).toSeq should not equal (Iterable(1, 2).toSeq) }
```

**edit 2:** For unordered collections where elements cannot be sorted, you can use this method:

```
  def sameAs[A](c: Traversable[A], d: Traversable[A]): Boolean = 
    if (c.isEmpty) d.isEmpty
    else {
      val (e, f) = d span (c.head !=)
      if (f.isEmpty) false else sameAs(c.tail, e ++ f.tail)
    }
```

e.g. (note use of symbols `'a 'b 'c` which have no defined ordering)

```
  test("7")  { assert( sameAs(Iterable(2, 1),    Iterable(1, 2)     )) }
  test("8")  { assert( sameAs(Array('a, 'c, 'b), List('c, 'a, 'b)   )) }
  test("9")  { assert( sameAs("cba",             Set('a', 'b', 'c') )) }
```

---

Alternative `sameAs` implementation:

```
  def sameAs[A](c: Traversable[A], d: Traversable[A]) = {
    def counts(e: Traversable[A]) = e groupBy identity mapValues (_.size)
    counts(c) == counts(d)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is very close to what I'm looking for, but not exactly: `toSet` eliminates duplicate values, so `Array(1, 1).toSet should not equal (Array(1))` incorrectly fails. From what I can tell, Scala does not have a MultiSet collection. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Michael good point, see my edit. If your items aren't ordered (i.e. you can't sort them), it might be a bit trickier

Comment: Defining an ordering isn't ideal, but it's a workable in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelKoval @Luigi Another alternative implementation of the `sameAs` method is `def sameAs[A](c: Traversable[A], d: Traversable[A]) = c.size == d.size && (c.toSeq diff d.toSeq).isEmpty`.

Comment: this answer is outdated. The ScalaTest API has been improved.

Comment: As @ChristophDittberner already said, ScalaTest 3.0 provides [Matchers to work with containers](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#workingWithAggregations).

Answer (score 108):

Meanwhile you can use

```
Iterable(2, 1) should contain theSameElementsAs Iterable(1, 2)
```

To test the ordered set you have to convert it to a sequence.

```
Set(1, 2).toSeq should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs List(1, 2)
```

Comment: re: second example. `Set` has no defined order, so the order when converted to a `Seq` is essentially random and you should never have a test whose result is dependent on that order. If you are using an ordered Set like `SortedSet` with `toSeq`, how is `should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs` different to `should equal`, aside from a catchier name?

Comment: Is there any way to get `sbt` to give a nicer output than `.... did not contain the same elements as ...`?  Specifically, it would be nice if it would tell me what's missing from a large collection.

Comment: How to use it recursively? Comparing case classes with a collection member is common.